# Spring's @Async managing threads

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I'm struggling with asynchronous processing in Spring. I've decided to use `@Acync` together with `@EnableAsync` and `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.
Is there any mechanism responsible for thread's hanging coming together with Spring's `@Async`? The Async method calls few external resources with RestTemplate and I should probably somehow protect against hanging a thread.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility of hanging thread with @Async is if request to any external resource goes to hang state due to some network or resource issue.

The solution would be, provide connection timeout for each external resource call.

Comment: Is it really enough to just set RestTemplate timeout in this case? Can we be sure that the thread will not hang somewhere in between?

Comment: Yes I am using this since last 6 month. The only issue of thread hanging we faced due to Database not returns response for infinite time.